# Good reference for how scala is mapped to jvm bytecode

Tags: scala, jvm, bytecode

Are there any good writeups of how the Scala compiler maps various Scala features to bytecode?

A quick google turned up the supporting material from David Pollak's 2009 talk

https://github.com/dpp/jvm_summit_2009/blob/master/scala_fancy_pants.pdf

But I suspect this may be both dated and incomplete.

I could try and gather this data myself via <s>scalap</s> javap, but it would be nice to benefit from someone elses effort and insight.

Comment: This probably changes from version to version. Have you tried looking at the compiler source? You can also just compile some classes and then disassemble them.

Comment: I could browse and try and understand the source, disassemble a bunch of scala or read a few years worth of the scala internals mailing list but I was hoping to find something to short cut all that. I'm lazy.

Comment: @Antimony I think you are correct that it changes from version to version. I'm most interested in 2.10.1 - but the upcoming changes to use java 1.7 jvm features are also of interest.

Comment: Well AFAIK, noone's bothered to writeup the internals of the Javac compiler, so a less popular language like Scala is unlikely to have something like that either. P.S. If you want to see what's really in the classfile, I'd recommend a disassembler like my Krakatau. Scalap is designed to make scala output pretty, but it's not going to show you the low level bytecode details.

Comment: @Antimony: "noone's bothered to writeup the internals of the Javac compiler...". He's asking for the scala<->bytecode mapping, that does not necessarily requires to understand the inner working of the compiler. Same difference as between the inner workings of javac vs the java<->bytecode mapping (the latter is rather well documented by the jvm specifcation alone). That said, even that is hardly documented (in the case of scala), at least not in a single place that I know of.

Comment: @henry: Antimony is right that using scalap won't be of much help given that it will show you a scala representation of the code (and not the raw bytecode). Javap is a better fit, there is even a `:javap` command in the REPL to easily decompile all kinds of test code (just make sure to have the `tools.jar` file from the jdk in your repl classpath).

Comment: @Regis Javap has the same problem, particularly with JDK7. That's why I recommended Krakatau, my own disassembler. It's specifically designed to be able to disassemble and reassemble any valid classfile, no matter how bizarre. As far as I know, the only current limitation is that it can't handle annotations nested more than 1000 deep.

Comment: Well, I never experienced any problem when dissemblinf scala classfiles using javap  (as opposed, obviously, to when decompiling to java, using any decompiler). Can you give give a specific scala code snippet that will fail with javap? Regarding jdk 7, if you are talking about this https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4936, then this only breaks the `:java` repl command, you can still call javap directly from your shell.

Comment: @Régis Jean-Gilles you're right, wrong tool. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 6):

on the Scala REPL, use `:javap -c` to see the generated bytecode.

For instance:

```
scala> class Bytes { def a = println("hello") }
defined class Bytes

scala> :javap -c Bytes
Compiled from "<console>"
public class Bytes extends java.lang.Object{
public void a();
  Code:
   0:   getstatic   #13; //Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
   3:   ldc #15; //String hello
   5:   invokevirtual   #19; //Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   8:   return

public Bytes();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #24; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware I can do this, but what I'm looking for is someone elses analysis rather than having to do me own.

Answer (score 1):

None that I'm aware of.
Consider using a bytecode inspection tool to inspect the code that the compiler produces. It is often useful when writing performance-critical code to verify whether specialization has been properly applied, closures eliminated, arrays are being accessed directly via bytecode instructions, macros properly expanded, etc.

If you are using Sublime, there is a this [plugin for viewing the bytecode](https://github.com/axel22/sublime-javap).